# I have a Python code that is given below, when I run this global name PDBAttributes is not defined

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7 
##-*- mode:python;tab-width:2;indent-tabs-mode:t;show-trailing-whitespace:t;rm-trailing-spaces:t;python-indent:2 -*-'

import noesy
import argparse
import library

parser =argparse.ArgumentParser(description="read pdb file",
                                add_help=True)

parser.add_argument("file",help="protein pdb file")

library.add_standard_args( parser )
args = parser.parse_args()

def read_structure(pdbfile):
        struct=[]
        for line in pdbfile:
                if len(line):
                        struct.append(PDBAttributes.read_from_line(line))
        return struct

pdb=read_structure(open(args.file,'r'))

class PDBAttributes:
    def __init__(self, atomindex=1, atom=noesy.Atom(), atomx=1, atomy=1, atomz=1):
        self._atomindex=atomindex
        self._atom=atom
        self._atomx=atomx
        self._atomy=atomy
        self._atomz=atomz

        def __str__(self):
        s='ATOM %(_atomindex)d %(_atom)s at %(_atomx)8.3f %(_atomy)8.3f %(_atomz)8.3f'%self.__dict__
        return s

    def atom(self):
        return self._atom

    def atomindex(self):
        return self._atomindex

    def atomx(self):
        return self._atomx

    def atomy(self):
        return self._atomy

    def atomz(self):
        return self._atomz

    @classmethod
    def read_from_line(obj,line):
        tags=line.split()
        atomindex=int(tags[1])
        atom=noesy.Atom(tags[2],int(tags[5]))
        atomx=float(tags[6])
        atomy=float(tags[7])
        atomz=float(tags[8])
        obj=PDBAttributes(atomindex, atom, atomx, atomy, atomz)
        print obj

class AtomDistance(PDBAttributes):

    def distance(self, atom1,atom2):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your call of `read_structure` to follow the definition of the `PDBAttributes` class.

Also, in the process of reformatting your post, I see that you have mixed tabs and spaces for your indentation. Try reformatting your code to use all spaces for indentation, the recommended form is 4-space indents.

Your definition of all those getter functions looks like Java written in Python - this is a lot of extra code that is often unnecessary in Python. The recommended approach is to omit these all-they-do-is-assign-a-value-to-an-attribute-with-the-same-name-but-with-a-leading-underscore methods and just use attributes with the public names.  See [Python is Not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `NameError` you are getting is due to the order you have placed the code in your file.

When you call `read_structure` to create a value for the `pdb` variable, it tries to look for `PDBAttributes`, but it has not been defined yet. If you move that line lower down in the file (below the class definition) you'll avoid that error. Note that it is OK to have the declaration of `read_structure` above the `PDBAttributes` class definition, though you might want to move it lower too to make the code easier to understand.

Here's a very simple bit of code that demonstrates the same error:

```
def foo():
    print(foo_text)

foo() # raises a NameError

foo_text = "foo"
```

Here's a fixed version:

```
def foo():
    print(foo_text)

foo_text = "foo"

foo() # no error, prints "foo"
```